# Overriding == does't seem to work in inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm working on a program that's part of a much larger program, but I created this simple application to demonstrate the issue I'm running into. Here is my code:

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bear = new Animal("Bear");
            var bear2 = new Animal("Bear");
            var dog = new Dog("Woof!", "Dog");
            var dog2 = new Dog("Bow-Wow!", "Dog");

            AreEqual(bear, bear2);
            AreEqual(dog2, dog);
        }

        private static void AreEqual(Animal animal1, Animal animal2)
        {
            if (animal1 == animal2)
                Console.WriteLine($"{animal1,15} == {animal2}");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{animal1,15} != {animal2}");
        }
    }

    public sealed class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string Action { get; }

        public static bool operator ==(Dog x, Dog y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name && x.Action == y.Action;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Dog x, Dog y)
        {
            return !(x.Name == y.Name && x.Action == y.Action);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!base.Equals(obj))
            {
                return false;
            }
            Dog rhs = (Dog)obj;
            return Action == rhs.Action;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode() ^ Action.GetHashCode();
        }

        public Dog(string action, string animalName) : base(animalName)
        {
            Action = action;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} ({Action})";
        }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public Animal(string animalName)
        {
            Name = animalName;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Animal x, Animal y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Animal x, Animal y)
        {
            return x.Name != y.Name;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
                return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
                return false;

            Animal rhs = obj as Animal;

            return Name == rhs.Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I am seeing this on the screen:

```
          Bear == Bear
Dog (Bow-wow!) == Dog (Woof!)
```

This is not correct. What I am expecting to see is this:

```
          Bear == Bear
Dog (Bow-wow!) != Dog (Woof!)
```

In the `Dog` class, I overrode the `==` operator which compares the `Name` fields and `Action` fields. Clearly the `Action` fields are different for each instance, so I'm not understanding why it's saying they are equal. Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure this is something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: Can you step through the code in debug session?

Comment: The method operates on `Animals`, not `Dogs`.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - Correct, but shouldn't polymorphism take over and call the correct method, like it does with `.ToString()`?

Comment: If you want the equality operator to consider the runtime type of the object you could change the method signature to accept `dynamic` instead

Comment: No because equality operators are static methods, and certainly not virtual like your `ToString` method.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 -- That's my issue then. I assumed that operators were virtual and the correct operator overload would be called at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `== operator` of `Animal` because `AreEqual()` is operating on Animals.  This operator is not a virtual method that is inherited.  You should use `Equals()` instead if you want inheritance

Comment: That's my issue then. I assumed that operators were virtual and the correct operator overload would be called at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The operators you are overloading are static, static to the class that it belongs to.

It has a similar concept as the `new` keyword instead of `override` keyword that you are hoping for.

you can read more about new vs override [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

basically the method gets executed is based on the type you cast it to. You are casting both objects to `Animal` inside

```
private static void AreEqual(Animal animal1, Animal animal2)
```

so the == operator for `Animal` gets executed.

if you just do

```
Console.WriteLine(dog == dog2);
```

it will return false.

Comment: What do `new` and `override` have to do with operator overloads / static methods?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 because oerator overload is a "new" overload instead of "override" overload

Comment: well since there's no such thing as a `static virtual` method a `static override` method would of course, not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (animal1 == animal2)
```

to

```
if (animal1.Equals(animal2))
```